# When passing a custom header through a GET request to API Gateway, it returns a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' CORS response

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to pass an access token as a header to a GET request into API Gateway, but every time it's returning: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

NOTE: I've setup the API Gateway resource with a proxy integration.

```
  exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
  const { access_token } = event.headers
          
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: getHeaders(),
    body: JSON.stringify({
      data: access_token,
    })
  }
  return response
}

const getHeaders = () => {
  return {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}
```

I've tried just about every combo returning different headers.

When I try running this request with the access_token as a query parameter it works just fine, it returns as expected, but not when passing as a header.

Something also worth noting, when I pass the access_token as a header through postman it'll return as expected, but when I call it from my UI application on localhost with axios is where it doesn't work.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: You have OPTIONS method with Integration Response `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` ,with all the headers including this access_token header?

Comment: The way I understand it, if you are using proxy integration on the API resource, then you control CORS through the lambda response?  So you can see I have my headers returning 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'.. That should function the same way?

Comment: You are passing OPTIONS request as well to Lambda and returning the headers ?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.

Comment: Then we need to add OPTIONS method pointing to Mock integration and return necessary headers in `Integration Response`, which is what API Gateway does when you enable CORS from console.

Comment: Okay, I've added the OPTIONS method pointing to Mock integration.  Within Integration Response I have a Method response status of 200, and within that I have a HTTP status regex of default, Content handling of "Passthrough", under Header Mappings for Response header I've added "access_token" with a corresponding Mapping value of "integration.response.header.access_token", but I'm still getting the CORS error from the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Api Gateway CORS, we need to add an additional OPTIONS method pointing to MOCK integration and with header mappings in integration response with

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` should contain all headers

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods` should contain all methods

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should contain the host or '*'

Example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'   (should contain all head
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'GET,OPTIONS' 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin :   '*'
```

Method Response:
[image]

Integration Response:

[image]

Comment: Great, that worked.  Thanks Balu.  In order to now pass my access_token header through I just had to add it to the Access-Control-Allow-Headers mapping value.

Comment: is it possible to set this through a SAM template.yml?

Comment: After my next deployment with the a SAM template it actually deleted my OPTIONS method for my resource.  Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please try [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-corsconfiguration.html#sam-property-api-corsconfiguration--examples)

Comment: My template.yml didn't have a APIGateway resource before adding this and I keep getting the following error in my CouldFormations>stacks>events : "The REST API doesn't contain any methods (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 66a829cb-4c28-47e9-b936-687eeacac1f4; Proxy: null)".

Answer (score 1):

By adding the following to my template.yml, after deploying SAM adds the OPTIONS method to each of my resource method within API Gateway. I needed to specify my specific header as well in the config, otherwise I would still get the same issue.

```
 Globals:
      Api:
        Cors:
          AllowMethods: "'GET,POST,OPTIONS'"
          AllowHeaders: "'access_token,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'"
          AllowOrigin: "'*'"
          AllowCredentials: "'*'"
```

Comment: Question doesn't say anything about using Sam, may be it's better to update the question otherwise the actual solution is adding OPTIONS method and sending back necessary headers with Mock integration, which will be added added by these steps in sam template

Comment: Thats fair, I've updated the answer to yours based on how I formed my question.